# How to capture username in gmail during runtime in selenium?

Tags: selenium

I have a scenario where I navigate to gmail login page.

I want the username editbox to capture the username during runtime.

Is it possible in selenium?

Answer (score -1):

`getAttribute(String str)` in `WebElement` should work.